# Maven repository for camunda 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, spring-boot, camunda

I'm following some instructions here on how to get started with a Spring Boot Camunda start up application.

```
https://camunda.github.io/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/docs/current/index.html
```

According to this link I should be able to find 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT on Maven central but I cannot.

```
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter
```

Maven central only has version 1.3.0.

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.extension/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter
```

Can someone help me with this. At the moment the only way I can get things working is by building the whole camunda-bpm-spring-boot project that I downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: Obviously they've just updated their documentation, but haven't actually published the new release. Current version in Maven is 1.3.0

Comment: thanks. Just making sure I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 3):

To use Camunda SpringBoot 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, you have to add the maven central snapshot repository to your project like so

```
<repository>
  <id>maven-central-snapshots</id>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

See [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/camunda/bpm/extension/springboot/) for the artifacts of 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT. You don't find them under the old location because the groupId and artifactIds changed a bit. Also there is no actual 2.0.0 release yet.

Comment: I just put a "caution" tag on the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: If you are willing to help testing you can of course use it, but it is under heavy development, subject of refactorings and not recommended for "I need a stable platform" projects. Expect the 2.0.0 release at the beginning of december.

Comment: Update: meanwhile 2.0.0 has been released on maven central!